# Stop SPD shoes from grinding

Tags: shoes, spd, cleat

I have a pair of Chrome Midway Pro SPD cycling shoes.  These look like sneakers, but have a cleat mount embedded in them.  Mine have worn down a bit and now the cleat crunches against the ground all the time.

What can I do to make the cleat stop grinding?  Maybe build up the front of the shoe around the opening with a few layers of gorilla tape or glue strips of old bike tires to the bottom of my shoe, any suggestions?

Comment: I work around this grinding sound, specially when I'm indoors with a beautiful floor, by walking mostly on the side part of the foot, thus lifting the medial part of the shoe a bit. If done with skill, it avoids the grinding and people around won't even notice you're walking a bit funny.

Comment: Either find some cleat covers or buy new shoes.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Just kick your shoes off before walking on your friends' tile or hardwood floors ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A cobbler (i.e. a shoe repairman) can glue a new layer of sole (e.g a non-slip rubber sole that's suitable for winter) onto a pair of shoes' existing soles: so perhaps ask a cobbler.

Comment: This. You need a cobbler. There's really nothing you can do personally that won't be destroyed the first few times you walk on it.

Answer (score 5):

They sell [cleat covers](http://www.exustar.com/product_detail.php?psn=152&level=2&t1s=31) you can use to protect the cleats, and the floors you walk on.  Most of them are for SPD-SL but (i think) the ones I linked to are for SPD.

Comment: I liked these! +1

Comment: Any experience with these?  How long do they last?

Comment: Sorry, no personal experience.  Found a link to Amazon, though they no longer sell them. There's a few reviews listed there. (http://www.amazon.com/Exustar-Cleat-Covers-for-SPD/dp/B001CJZC4W/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top)

Answer (score 1):

I wear Chrome shoes as well, but only have the regular Midways.

Chrome, although their shoes are less than satisfactory (for me), have excellent customer service, and I mean EXCELLENT.

If you have some sort of defect on your shoe, take it into one of their shops, and they'll replace it for you. (Within the 1 year warranty)

Mine was splitting on the sides between the sole and the plastic band that's glued onto the shoe.

They replaced it no questions asked, and extended my warranty 1 year past the day of replacement.

That being said, this would only work if you bought your shoe less than one year ago, and still have the receipt.